# How can I re-enable keyboard typing? From voice?

Tags: keyboard, voice-typing

I'm now stuck with Voice Input as the only typing mode because I accidentally chose it.

How can I re-enable keyboard typing?

Comment: Can you share screenshot?  And what android version  u r using?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to choose a default keyboard (i.e. Google Keyboard instead of Google voice typing) through your settings. Navigate to `Settings -> Language and Input` (titled similarly on most devices), then select an option other than voice input. If necessary, you can deselect the voice typing option to disable it entirely. The screen should look something like this:

[image]